# Transform Numbers - Trim Integral Part from Floating Point Number

Tags: r, decimal

Given a column of data (of the type 39600.432, 39600.433, etc) I would like to drop the integer part of the number and keep only the decimals (transforming 39600.432 into 432, and 39600.433 into 433). How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to convert 39600.400 into 4, or 400?

Comment: 400 is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say your column is the vector x.

```
> x <- c(39.456, 976.902)
> x <- x - as.integer(x)
> x
[1] 0.456 0.902
```

That should work.  You can then just multiply by 1000 to convert the current x to integers.  You will need some more processing if you want 3.9 to become 9.

```
> x <- 1000*x
> x
[1] 456 902
```

Hope the helps!

Comment: Thank you all for the quick and great answers!! I think I will use this first one.

Comment: Then can you 'tick' to accept it as an answer and address the important comment made on the question about 123.400 being 4 or 400.

Answer (score 4):

Many good answers, here's one more using regular expressions.

```
> g <- c(134.3412,14234.5453)
> gsub("^[^\\.]*\\.", "", g)
[1] "3412" "5453"
```

Comment: `.` needn't be escaped when present in a character class.

Answer (score 4):

To strip the integral part without a subtraction or regex, you can use the modulus operator.

```
x <- (10000:10010)/100
x
## [1] 100.00 100.01 100.02 100.03 100.04 100.05 100.06 100.07 100.08 100.09 100.10
x %% 1
## [1] 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10
```

`%% 1` is meaningful in R.  This does leave the value as fractional, which may not be ideal for your use.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `floor` function. But you could do `as.integer` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using regular expressions

```
g<-c(134.3412,14234.5453)
r<-regexpr("[0-9]+$",g)
as.numeric(regmatches(g,r))
```

Comment: I think `r<-regexpr("[0-9]+$",g)` because the OP did not want it as a decimal fraction but rather as an integer.

Comment: @DWin Thanks for catching that. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
g <- c(134.3412,14234.5453)
h <- floor(g)
g - h
```

Comment: Why and how does that work.Please give an explanation in the answer

Comment: floor rounds down. h is vector of integers rounded down from g. Then you subtract h from g to give you the decimal points.